# Pythonic way to simplify multiply 2 pandas columns with condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I am looking for a way how I can simplify below examples:

```
self.df[TARGET_NAME] = self.df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['WINNER'] == 1 and row['WINNER_OVER_2_5'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
```

like:

> self.df[TARGET_NAME] = self.df[(self.df.WINNER == 1)] &
>   self.df[(self.df.WINNER_OVER_2_5 == 1)] # not it's not correct

and more complex as below

```
df["PROFIT"] = np.where((df[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 0),
                                  df['MATCH_HOME'] * df['HOME_STAKE'],
                                  np.where((dfml[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 1),
                                           df['MATCH_DRAW'] * df['DRAW_STAKE'],
                                           np.where((df[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 2),
                                                    df['MATCH_AWAY'] * df['AWAY_STAKE'],
                                                    -0))).astype(float)
```

Comment: IIUC you can use `df['TARGET_NAME'] = np.where((df.WINNER.isin([1]) & df.WINNER_OVER_2_5.isin([1])),1,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print df
   WINNER  WINNER_OVER_2_5
0       1                0
1       1                1
2       0                2

df['TARGET_NAME'] = np.where((df.WINNER.isin([1]) & df.WINNER_OVER_2_5.isin([1])),1,0)
print df
   WINNER  WINNER_OVER_2_5  TARGET_NAME
0       1                0            0
1       1                1            1
2       0                2            0
```

EDIT (untested, because no data):

```
df["PROFIT"] = np.where((df[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"].isin([0])),
                                  df['MATCH_HOME'] * df['HOME_STAKE'],
                                  np.where((dfml[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"].isin([1])),
                                           df['MATCH_DRAW'] * df['DRAW_STAKE'],
                                           np.where((df[TARGET_NAME] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"].isin([2])),
                                                    df['MATCH_AWAY'] * df['AWAY_STAKE'],
                                                    0))).astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I got, the second example above is already simplified? :)

Comment: For some datasets and your example #1, catch `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: the same `df`, I don't understand why issue happend

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way how I can simplify below examples:

I guess you're looking for a simpler syntax. How about this:

```
df['MATCH'] = matches(df, values=(0,1), WINNER=1, WINNER_OVER_2_5=1)
```

Note that `values=` is optional and takes any `tuple(false-value, true-value)`, defaulting to `(False, True)`.

To get there it takes a bit of magic. Essentially this builds a truth table by chaining the conditions and transforming the result into the values as specified. It ends up doing the same thing as your `lambda`, just in a generic way.

```
def matches(df, values=None, **kwargs):
    values = values or (False, True)
    flt = None
    for var, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        t = (df[var] == value)
        flt = (flt & t) if flt is not None else t
    flt = flt.apply(lambda t : values[t])
    return flt
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with  boolean attribute

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0],'b' :[1,1,0,np.nan]})

df['NEW']= ((df['a']==1 ) &  (df['b']==1)).astype(int).fillna(0)
```